# Download file programatically by using anonymous link to file

Tags: sharepoint-online, anonymous-authentication, php, file-download

I have got an anonymous link to a necessary file placed on SharePoint. Is there any option to download that file using automation?

I need to do this using PHP. If it is not possible using PHP then C# would work too.

I tried to search for a solution over internet, but all results I got includes signing in to SharePoint - that is not an option for me because I do not have credentials.

Comment: You will be able to only if anonymous users are allowed to the SharePoint web application. Or else it is not possible. This is actually one advantage of SharePoint security.